# Does armor affect spellcasting?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, armor

I am currently using a wizard. I was wondering, if I decided to take a feat that would allow me to use heavier than light armor, would that affect my spellcasting?

I thought I read something about it in the rule book but I can't find it.

Comment: This is a plain read-the-book-to-me question. You are supposed to read the book yourself. Please note that we are [not too fond](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/what-do-we-do-with-read-the-book-to-me-questions) of questions that only ask for answers that the book already gives.

Comment: @nvoigt for the record, and recognizing I'm in the minority here,  I don't mind, and welcome, questions of any level of knowledge or research. Not everyone has access or is familiar with digitally searchable material, and navigating the books can be tricky.

Answer (score 14):

Rules for casting in armour can be found on page 201 of the PHB and are as follows:

> **Casting in Armour**
>   Because of the mental focus  and precise gestures  required for spellcasting, you  must be proficient with the armour you are wearing to cast a spell. You  are otherwise too distracted and  physically hampered  by your armour for spellcasting.

The *Lightly Armoured, Moderately Armoured,* and *Heavily Armoured* feats all give you proficiency with their respective armour categories. This means that you would be able to cast spells if you take one, two, or all three of these feats and are wearing the appropriate armour.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I know what feat to take next now. Thank you!

Comment: You forgot the moderately armored feat.  :D

Answer (score 4):

Page 201 of the PHB says that you must be proficient in the armor that you are wearing in order to cast the spell.

That being said, there is a Medium Armor feat (Moderately Armored) that you can take to upgrade from light armor. There is also a Heavy armor feat (Heavily Armored), but it requires medium armor proficiency.